# If you have a boolean function with only "true" and "don't care" (no false) outcomes, how would you write the equation?

Tags: boolean-algebra

In my homework I came across a situation where I had a Karnaugh map that only contained don't cares and trues. Since there are no false outputs possible, it seems like the equation would just be f(x,y,z) = TRUE.  Am I right or am I missing something?

Comment: If there are k "don't care"s in the map, there are 2^k possibilities.  But I'd use the simplest one, f = true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That sounds about right to me - your specification is basically for a circuit that outputs 1 or anything, so outputting 1 is correct.